# Sorting numerically with text stored values

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sorting, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 which contains physical cable connection data.  In this table is an nchar field (text) which stores device port numbers.  This field cannot be an integer because some ports are "GE0" or "1/15".

When a query is run to retrieve data from this table, it is sorted ascending by port number.  The problem is, because the field stores text, I get text sorted results like this:

```
1/0
1/4
10/4
10/8
11/2
12/19
2/4
3/2
```

Instead, I'd like the results to be formatted ascending so that these ports appear in an order like this:

```
1/0
1/4
2/4
3/2
10/4
10/8
11/2
12/19
```

My problem is that I haven't the slightest clue where to begin.  This data is presented through a website running on Classic ASP (VBScript), so some reorganizing can be done there after the recordset is retrieved.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: is it always number/number or the values like you mentioned "GE0" also present? if so - how do u want to sort those?

Answer (score 1):

To satisfy the primary sort requirement (I missed the secondary which @EricZ caught):

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, LEFT(column_name, CHARINDEX('/', column_name)-1));
```

To avoid conversion errors with values like `GE0`, you will have to say:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN column_name NOT LIKE '%[^/0-9]%' THEN
  CONVERT ... END
```

Even with a `WHERE` clause to filter those out, you can't guarantee whether the filter will happen before any conversion is attempted.

Of course this is going to be a pretty expensive sort operation - you are much better off either separating these two *separate* pieces of information in advance (e.g. storing them as separate columns) or maybe adding a computed column.

Answer (score 1):

If all your data have same format, How about try this?

```
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(column_name,'/','.') AS NUMERIC(19,4))
```

Comment: Yes I missed the secondary sort requirement, in which case this is better. However the disclaimer in my answer still applies so I'm going to leave it there.

Comment: Okay, I've had some moderate success with this, in the sense that it lists the items to the left of the / in numerical order, however it still lists the items to the right of the / in text order.  So I'm seeing results like this:

1/23

2/0

2/1

2/20

2/2

2/21

10/24

10/27

I seem to be having trouble with a new line in the comments...  Hopefully that came through clearly...